# Parsing string to JSON using node gives unexpected token, validator says ok

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

I have the following string that I would like to parse to JSON :

```
{
    "STATUS": [
        {
            "STATUS": "S",
            "When": 1394044643,
            "Code": 17,
            "Msg": "GPU0",
            "Description": "cgminer 3.7.3"
        }
    ],
    "GPU": [
        {
            "GPU": 0,
            "Enabled": "Y",
            "Status": "Alive",
            "Temperature": 70,
            "Fan Speed": 3089,
            "Fan Percent": 70,
            "GPU Clock": 1180,
            "Memory Clock": 1500,
            "GPU Voltage": 1.206,
            "GPU Activity": 99,
            "Powertune": 20,
            "MHS av": 0.4999,
            "MHS 5s": 0.5009,
            "Accepted": 4335,
            "Rejected": 7,
            "Hardware Errors": 0,
            "Utility": 27.8007,
            "Intensity": "0",
            "Last Share Pool": 0,
            "Last Share Time": 1394044643,
            "Total MH": 4676.7258,
            "Diff1 Work": 69436,
            "Difficulty Accepted": 69360,
            "Difficulty Rejected": 112,
            "Last Share Difficulty": 16,
            "Last Valid Work": 1394044643,
            "Device Hardware%": 0,
            "Device Rejected%": 0.1613,
            "Device Elapsed": 9356
        }
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

When I use e.g. http://jsonlint.com/ it says that the JSON is correct but when I use in node.js:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
```

I get the following :

```
undefined:1
e Hardware%":0.0000,"Device Rejected%":0.1570,"Device Elapsed":9554}],"id":1}
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Any clue what am I doing wrong here ?

**EDIT**

The data is coming as ByteStream :

```
.on('data',function(data){
  console.log(data.toString());
  console.log();
  console.log(data);
  console.log();
  console.log("data "+ data.GPU);
  //...

//...
{"STATUS":[{"STATUS":"S","When":1394045650,"Code":17,"Msg":"GPU0","Description":"cgminer 3.7.3"}],"GPU":[{"GPU":0,"Enabled":"Y","Status":"Alive","Temperature":70.00,"Fan Speed":3090,"Fan Percent":70,"GPU Clock":1180,"Memory Clock":1500,"GPU Voltage":1.206,"GPU Activity":99,"Powertune":20,"MHS av":0.4999,"MHS 5s":0.5007,"Accepted":4841,"Rejected":8,"Hardware Errors":0,"Utility":28.0261,"Intensity":"0","Last Share Pool":0,"Last Share Time":1394045638,"Total MH":5181.3734,"Diff1 Work":77548,"Difficulty Accepted":77456.00000000,"Difficulty Rejected":128.00000000,"Last Share Difficulty":16.00000000,"Last Valid Work":1394045638,"Device Hardware%":0.0000,"Device Rejected%":0.1651,"Device Elapsed":10364}],"id":1} 

<Buffer 7b 22 53 54 41 54 55 53 22 3a 5b 7b 22 53 54 41 54 55 53 22 3a 22 53 22 2c 22 57 68 65 6e 22 3a 31 33 39 34 30 34 35 32 34 38 2c 22 43 6f 64 65 22 3a 31 ...>

data undefined
```

**EDIT**

When I do this :

```
console.log(data.toString());
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.toString()));
```

I get the following result :

```
"{"STATUS":[{"STATUS":"S","When":1394046864,"Code":17,"Msg":"GPU0","Description":"cgminer 3.7.3"}],"GPU":[{"GPU":0,"Enabled":"Y","Status":"Alive","Temperature":70.00,"Fan Speed":3087,"Fan Percent":70,"GPU Clock":1180,"Memory Clock":1500,"GPU Voltage":1.206,"GPU Activity":99,"Powertune":20,"MHS av":0.5000,"MHS 5s":0.5016,"Accepted":5396,"Rejected":8,"Hardware Errors":0,"Utility":27.9597,"Intensity":"0","Last Share Pool":0,"Last Share Time":1394046864,"Total MH":5789.2352,"Diff1 Work":86428,"Difficulty Accepted":86336.00000000,"Difficulty Rejected":128.00000000,"Last Share Difficulty":16.00000000,"Last Valid Work
":1394046864,"Device Hardware%":0.0000,"Device Rejected%":0.1481,"Device Elapsed":11580}],"id":1}"
"{\"STATUS\":[{\"STATUS\":\"S\",\"When\":1394046864,\"Code\":17,\"Msg\":\"GPU0\",\"Description\":\"cgminer 3.7.3\"}],\"GPU\":[{\"GPU\":0,\"Enabled\":\"Y\",\"Status\":\"Alive\",\"Temperature\":70.00,\"Fan Sp
eed\":3087,\"Fan Percent\":70,\"GPU Clock\":1180,\"Memory Clock\":1500,\"GPU Voltage\":1.206,\"GPU Activity\":99,\"Powertune\":20,\"MHS av\":0.5000,\"MHS 5s\":0.5016,\"Accepted\":5396,\"Rejected\":8,\"Hardw
are Errors\":0,\"Utility\":27.9597,\"Intensity\":\"0\",\"Last Share Pool\":0,\"Last Share Time\":1394046864,\"Total MH\":5789.2352,\"Diff1 Work\":86428,\"Difficulty Accepted\":86336.00000000,\"Difficulty Re
jected\":128.00000000,\"Last Share Difficulty\":16.00000000,\"Last Valid Work\":1394046864,\"Device Hardware%\":0.0000,\"Device Rejected%\":0.1481,\"Device Elapsed\":11580}],\"id\":1}\u0000"
```

Notice the last unicode character of the second message `\u0000` what can I do with it?

Comment: `data` is already a JSON object. You're converting it to a String with `toString()` and then parsing it back to JSON immediately... Simply use `data` as-is.

Comment: @AndréDion: If it's JSON, it's a string, though it could be a `String` object wrapper. Using `.toString()` is harmless. And `JSON.parse` doesn't turn it back into JSON. It takes the JSON and turns it into JavaScript objects.

Comment: @cookiemonster JSON is not a string. It's a stricter subset of an object literal. `JSON.parse` takes a String and converts to a true object literal.

Comment: Can you post more code? Are you sure that's the *exact* response you're getting?

Comment: @AndréDion: JSON is Unicode text. How can it be Unicode text and not be a string of characters? JSON is for data transmission. You're confusing JSON data and JavaScript objects. Yes, `JSON.parse` converts it to an object (not object literal, which is syntax). Once it's converted, it's no longer JSON.

Comment: Take a look at my edit guys.

Comment: I don't remember how NodeJS's buffers work. What do you get when you do `data.toString()`? Do you get the result you show at the top of your question?

Comment: I see  no reason why that should fail. I think perhaps we're missing some important code.

Comment: So if you do `console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()).GPU);` it fails?

Comment: @cookiemonster yes, the same way.

Comment: Can you post the entire `Buffer` output. Right now it trails with `...`

Comment: @cookiemonster Check out my edit - the last character there is a `\u0000`.

Comment: That should be fixed at the source if you control it.

Answer (score 11):

The problem was with the terminating null character. After removing it I can now parse the string no problemo ( post more efficient way if you have it)

```
var re = /\0/g;
str = data.toString().replace(re, "");
var o = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(o);
```

or

```
var str = data.toString().slice(0, - 1);
```

or work directly on bytes in `Buffer`

```
var buf = data.slice(0,data.length-1);
console.log(JSON.parse(buf.toString()));
```

Comment: This worked for me, string was being passed from java, the transfer had appended a null

Answer (score 3):

I copied your console log output for data.toString() and and as @patryk pointed out, there is a unicode character \u0000 at the end of the string. That might be causing the problem. I removed the trailing character, assigned the string to a variable and created a buffer out of it and everything is hunky dory.

```
var a = '{"STATUS":[{"STATUS":"S","When":1394045650,"Code":17,"Msg":"GPU0","Description":"cgminer 3.7.3"}],"GPU":[{"GPU":0,"Enabled":"Y","Status":"Alive","Temperature":70.00,"Fan Speed":3090,"Fan Percent":70,"GPU Clock":1180,"Memory Clock":1500,"GPU Voltage":1.206,"GPU Activity":99,"Powertune":20,"MHS av":0.4999,"MHS 5s":0.5007,"Accepted":4841,"Rejected":8,"Hardware Errors":0,"Utility":28.0261,"Intensity":"0","Last Share Pool":0,"Last Share Time":1394045638,"Total MH":5181.3734,"Diff1 Work":77548,"Difficulty Accepted":77456.00000000,"Difficulty Rejected":128.00000000,"Last Share Difficulty":16.00000000,"Last Valid Work":1394045638,"Device Hardware%":0.0000,"Device Rejected%":0.1651,"Device Elapsed":10364}],"id":1}';

var b = new Buffer(a);

console.log(JSON.parse(b.toString());
```

**output** -

```
{ STATUS: 
   [ { STATUS: 'S',
       When: 1394045650,
       Code: 17,
       Msg: 'GPU0',
       Description: 'cgminer 3.7.3' } ],
  GPU: 
   [ { GPU: 0,
       Enabled: 'Y',
       Status: 'Alive',
       Temperature: 70,
       'Fan Speed': 3090,
       'Fan Percent': 70,
       'GPU Clock': 1180,
       'Memory Clock': 1500,
       'GPU Voltage': 1.206,
       'GPU Activity': 99,
       Powertune: 20,
       'MHS av': 0.4999,
       'MHS 5s': 0.5007,
       Accepted: 4841,
       Rejected: 8,
       'Hardware Errors': 0,
       Utility: 28.0261,
       Intensity: '0',
       'Last Share Pool': 0,
       'Last Share Time': 1394045638,
       'Total MH': 5181.3734,
       'Diff1 Work': 77548,
       'Difficulty Accepted': 77456,
       'Difficulty Rejected': 128,
       'Last Share Difficulty': 16,
       'Last Valid Work': 1394045638,
       'Device Hardware%': 0,
       'Device Rejected%': 0.1651,
       'Device Elapsed': 10364 } ],
  id: 1 }
```

Comment: JSON allows leading and trailing whitespace. `JSON.parse('   \n\n\t\t   {"foo":"bar"}   \n\n\t\t   ')`

Comment: JSON is completely whitespace-insensitive, outside of quoted strings.

Comment: I didn't check the string in a hex editor. Maybe it's some illegal invisible character

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly